# Obtener varios datos en una sola consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos mysql del indice de un curso

```
(id,tipo,titulo,completado)
```

Guardo los distintos tipos que componen el indice (clases, ejercicios y exámenes). Yo necesito saber cuantos ejercicios, clases y examenes tiene el curso podria hacerlo asi:

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM indice_curso WHERE tipo=examen;
SELECT COUNT() FROM indice_curso WHERE tipo=clase;
SELECT COUNT() FROM indice_curso WHERE tipo=ejercicio;
```

Pero son 3 consultas, es posible hacerlo en 1 consulta?. Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: Añade la consulta que haz intentado hasta el momento para que podamos ayudarte mejor

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de que tu pregunta cumpla con los requerimientos del sitio, pero la resuesta es que si, en una solo consulta puedes traer todos los campos de una tabla y hasta de otras tablas

Comment: Hola , de ser posible adjunta las tablas para poder orientarte mejor :)

Comment: Hola por favor re formula tu pregunta  y colocas el código de **sql** y **php** para poderte ayudar.

Comment: La respuesta es **sí**, básicamente puedes obtener toda la información que estés almacenando. Ahora, si tu pregunta va más enfocada a cómo hacerlo, será necesario editar tu pregunta con los detalles de las tablas y los avances que has tenido para poder ayudarte de una forma más puntual y no caer en especulación :D

Comment: Ya refurmule la pregunta, espero se entienda. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Luego de la edición de la pregunta, te recomendaría usar la operacion de conjuntos UNION:

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM indice_curso WHERE tipo=examen
UNION
SELECT COUNT() FROM indice_curso WHERE tipo=clase
UNION
SELECT COUNT() FROM indice_curso WHERE tipo=ejercicio
```

Creo que es lo que buscas

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Federico!, ya reformule la pregunta, espero haberme explicado mejor. Gracias!

Comment: Creo que con eso podrás

Answer (score 1):

Al menos en SQL Server se puede se puede resolver así, yo supongo que en mysql vas a poder hacer algo parecido:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tipo=examen THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN tipo=clase THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN tipo=ejercicio THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       FROM indice_curso
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar una sentencia parecida a esta:

```
    SELECT COUNT() FROM indice_curso WHERE (tipo = 'examen' OR tipo = 'clase' OR tipo = 'ejercicio');
```

Creo que te puede ayudar.